# Jekyll - Error Running 'Jekyll Serve'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

EDIT: Found the answer (see my answer below!). It involves using version 1.4.2 instead of 1.4.3, so if anyone has any ideas on getting 1.4.3 working, that could be helpful as well. Thanks!

EDIT 2: Thanks to a comment below, it seems that 1.4.3 does have a problem when running on windows. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1948

I have just setup jekyll on my windows 7 computer. I have ruby installed along with the dev pack.

I have run `gem install jekyll` and that completed with success. I have created a new site as per the jekyll documentation.

The problem I am experiencing happens when I try to run `jekyll serve`. Please find below the error output.

```
PS C:\jekyll\test-site> jekyll serve --trace
Configuration file: C:/jekyll/test-site/_config.yml
        Source: C:/jekyll/test-site
   Destination: C:/jekyll/test-site/_site
  Generating... C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Invalid argument - C:/jekyll/test-site/_site/C: (Errno::EINVAL)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/convertible.rb:168:in `write'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:259:in `block in write'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:397:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:396:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:396:in `block in each_site_file'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:395:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:395:in `each_site_file'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:259:in `write'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:41:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command.rb:18:in `process_site'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:23:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:7:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/jekyll:97:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:78:in `run!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>
```

I have looked around but am a novice with ruby, so I have no idea what to look for or how to find the error here. Any help would be much appriciated.

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Can you try a new site "testsite" (no dash)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @svoop I gave that a go but no luck, same error.

Comment: This same issue happens with 'jekyll build' also.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Answering my own question, I managed to find a solution.

This appears to be a problem with Jekyll version 1.4.3. To fix the issue I uninstalled jekyll and installed version 1.4.2.

`gem uninstall jekyll`

`gem install jekyll --version "=1.4.2"`

Doing this and everything should work fine if you have the same issue as me on windows.

I guess this is because version 1.4.3 is new (released on 13th) and is unstable on windows.

Comment: Thanks Joe. FWIW I was looking to use Jekyll to preview my github pages before I pushed them. This meant, having followed their instructions, I needed to alter a reference to Jekyll found in a generated file called Gemfile.Lock. after I did this things started working for me locally.

Comment: @RoryBecker I can `build` and `serve`, but `serve --watch` throws me an error. Is this somehow related with what you said? Because I didn't find any references to jekyll in the Gemfile.Lock-files.

Comment: I had the same problem with `jekyll serve --watch`. You need to install some other gems for that. I think the gem is called `listener` but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Has anyone here raised a related issue on Jekyll for this? It's a workaround - but probably needs a bug report.

Comment: I believe it was raised on Jekyll (See github link in my main question.) It seems that they have said they would be fixing it for version 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same issue with Jekyll's plugin "Category Archive Generator" (https://github.com/shigeya/jekyll-category-archive-plugin)

Most likely you have a plugin - in the _plugins folder - which is using the File.join() method. e.g.  `File.join('/', dest, @dir, @category_dir_name, 'index.html')`

Modify this by deleting the first element leaving you with `File.join(dest, @dir, @category_dir_name, 'index.html')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I have no plugins installed at all. The _plugins folder is not there, and I am on a fresh install.

Comment: With your previous answer and https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1948 I see that the culprit is 1.4.3 in and of itself.

Comment: I've looked at the source code from the gem, i.e. `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/` it doesn't look as though the `destination` methods in `post.rb` and `page.rb` matches those at GitHub https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/post.rb and https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/page.rb

If you were to swap them out in you gems internals, then 1.4.3 works. You could delete the method in `post.rb` and `page.rb` if you add the correct method to `convertible.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu Precise 12.04. The issue was that I had ruby1.8 installed. I also had ruby1.9.1 installed. I removed ruby1.8, and then Jekyll installed fine.