# Jekyll serve "Error: Invalid argument" issue

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm currently running through the stages of installing and generating a Jekyll site locally on my Windows 7 PC. I've installed all the requirements and can get Jekyll to initiate, but I can't get it to serve. Whenever I try it returns the following error:

```
    $ jekyll serve -t
Configuration file: c:/wamp/www/ShaunYearStrong.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: c:/wamp/www/ShaunYearStrong.github.io
       Destination: c:/wamp/www/ShaunYearStrong.github.io/_site
      Generating... c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Inval
id argument - c:/wamp/www/ShaunYearStrong.github.io/_site/c: (Errno::EINVAL)
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in
mkdir_p'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/convert
ible.rb:168:in `write'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:259:in `block in write'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:397:in `block (2 levels) in each_site_file'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:396:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:396:in `block in each_site_file'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:395:in `each'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:395:in `each_site_file'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:259:in `write'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb
:41:in `process'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command
.rb:18:in `process_site'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:23:in `build'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/lib/jekyll/command
s/build.rb:7:in `process'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jekyll-1.4.3/bin/jekyll:97:in `
block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:180:in `call'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/c
ommand.rb:155:in `run'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/r
unner.rb:78:in `run!'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/d
elegates.rb:11:in `run!'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/commander-4.1.5/lib/commander/i
mport.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See this answer
[Use Jekyll 1.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137096/jekyll-error-running-jekyll-serve)

```
gem uninstall jekyll

gem install jekyll --version "=1.4.2"
```